# Is there a Javascript or Jquery script that emulates Stack Overflow's flash message (the orange bar on top)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

It's a neat looking script that I can't seem to find anywhere. Any idea on where you can find a script like it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like [this (jquery notifications plugin)](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/notifications)?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the stackoverflow source when you get one of those.  Turn your cookies off to get the "first time" message, if you want an easy way.  The page references:

http://sstatic.net/so/js/master.js?v=4700

And there's a bit of script that calls

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() { notify.showFirstTime(); });
</script>
```

That's the script that does it.  Go into that master.js file and find that method.